# TODO Highlight not working when listing all highlights in Laravel

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, laravel-5.7

I wish to show all `TODO:` and `FIXME:` notes in my `.blade.php` files. But is fails to do so, it's just showing 0% searching in the lower left part and nothing happens.

I pasted this setting in my `settings.json`:

```
"todohighlight.include": [
        "**/*.js",
        "**/*.jsx",
        "**/*.ts",
        "**/*.tsx",
        "**/*.html",
        "**/*.php",
        "**/*.css",
        "**/*.scss",
        "**/*.blade.php"
    ]
```

I already included `.blade.php` in the list, am I missing something? Should I paste something more? by the way the version of my VS Code is `1.31.1`.

I apologize if my tagging to this questions is wrong, let me know so I may edit it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need define style highlights for TODO and FIXME:

Example settings.xml

```
"todohighlight.keywords": [
        {
            "text": "NOTE:",
            "color": "#ecf0f1",
            "border": "1px solid #2980b9",
            "borderRadius": "4px",
            "backgroundColor": "#3498db",
        },
        {
            "text": "HACK:",
            "color": "#ecf0f1",
            "border": "1px solid #8e44ad",
            "borderRadius": "4px",
            "backgroundColor": "#9b59b6",
        },
        {
            "text": "FIXME:",
            "color": "#ecf0f1",
            "border": "1px solid #f39c12",
            "borderRadius": "4px",
            "backgroundColor": "#f1c40f",
        },
        {
            "text": "BUG:",
            "color": "#ecf0f1",
            "border": "1px solid #c0392b",
            "borderRadius": "4px",
            "backgroundColor": "#e74c3c",
        },
        {
            "text": "TODO:",
            "color": "#ecf0f1",
            "border": "1px solid #27ae60",
            "borderRadius": "4px",
            "backgroundColor": "#2ecc71",
        }
]
```

Reference: https://github.com/wayou/vscode-todo-highlight/issues/93